# is there way to capture appointment discard event using outlook add-in/office-js

Tags: office-js, outlook-web-addins, office365-apps, office-js-helpers

Outlook add-ins provides a way to handle email or block email users from certain actions [using](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.application.itemsend)

```
Application.ItemSend event
```

is there similar way to capture discard click event through the office-js.?
I need to call 3rd party api if user decided to discard the appointment.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Application.ItemSend event is a part of VSTO add-ins and not outlook web addins.

Currently discard event is not a part of the product. We track Outlook add-in feature requests on our user-voice page. Please add your request there. Feature requests on user-voice are considered when we go through our planning process.

https://officespdev.uservoice.com/forums/224641-general/category/131778-outlook-add-ins